# LaTeXiT not compatible with macOS Sierra?

Tags: mac, latexit

I updated to Sierra today and found that LaTeXiT shipped with MacTeX cannot be launched any more. (The icon keeps bouncing in the Dock.)  Anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: What version of MacTeX and LaTeXiT  are you using? I certainly have no problem with LaTeXiT LaTeXIT 2.8.1 is the latest version.

Comment: 2016 MacTeX. For LaTeXiT, I tried both the version shipped with MacTeX and 2.8.1. Neither works for me.

Comment: Please report this to the author of LaTeXiT. Go to <[https://pierre.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-home.php](https://pierre.chachatelier.fr/latexit/latexit-home.php)>.

Comment: It turns out that the issue is not due to LaTeXiT but Sierra, since some other apps exhibit the same symptom. I reinstalled Sierra and the issue is gone. There must be some corruption during the earlier system updating process.